# Адаптивная сетка с одним фиксированным блоком

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать такие адаптивные колонки, с одним фиксированным по середине блоком?
Может плагины есть какие-то?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да повесьте этот блок посередине экрана с position: fixed;